# Get DSL Jobs from another GitHub Repo

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am currently learning Jenkins and I figured that it would be smarter to have the Groovy files separated from the source code.

What I am trying to do is to use "*get_jenkins_files.groovy*" from [Source code repository](https://github.com/Julian52575/Incredible_Math) to get the other groovy files from
[Jenkins job repository](https://github.com/Julian52575/Jenkins) and execute them.

I changed the "*get_jenkins_files.grovvy*" multiple times to no avail.

As of now, it looks like this :

```
job( 'Get Jenkins Files' ) {
    scm {
        github( 'Julian52575/Jenkins.git' )
    }

    steps {
        shell( 'git clone git@github.com:Julian52575/Jenkins2.git a' )
        systemGroovyCommand( 'a/dsl_math.groovy' )
        systemGroovyCommand( 'a/ls_math.groovy' )
        systemGroovyCommand( 'a/null.groovy' )
    }
}
```

None of the cloned jobs seems to be ran because I modified the repo name to one that doesn't exist and called the "*null.groovy*" file, who doesn't exist either, and I still have a build SUCCESS
The console prints this message :

> git checkout -f eb4acb8d6f6c3ddb92a08a2bb91725a1e555f261 # timeout=10

> Commit message: "test] non existing repo"

> git rev-list --no-walk 2aac20ca321b33f83280d9e545af0e8771235c18 # timeout=10

> Processing DSL script get_jenkins_files.groovy

> Existing items:

> GeneratedJob{name='Get Jenkins Files'}

> Math freestyle] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1914244833218209724.sh

> ls

> Makefile
> README.md
> get_jenkins_files.groovy
> src

> Finished: SUCCESS

Does anyone have any idea on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shared libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) is exactly match for your goal

For **Dsl jobs** you may use [multiscm plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-multiscm) (Deperecated) and i belive you need to use [pipelineJob](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob) rather than groovyCommand

In **pipeline** you can use **checkout** step

```
checkout scmGit(
  branches: [[name: '*/master']],
  extensions: [],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[
   credentialsId: 'my_jenkins_git_creds',
   url: 'https://my_git_repo/service.git']])
```

You may use it with **dir** step, or with checkout to subdir behavior (check it in pipeline syntax snippet generator)

P.S. for learning purposes DSL jobs plugin - is not good. You will have some troubles and misunderstanding with moving to pipelines.

Comment: Thank you very much !

It took me several hours but I managed to get a Shared Library working ! (Special thanks for the link you provided). I struggled with an "UnknowHost ERROR : api.github.com " for a while because I used a wrong link for the GitHub repository :( .